# how to attach an arrow at the end of ellipsis dots

Tags: html, css, ellipsis

How do I place the arrow icon at the end of the ellipsis dots?

The arrow icon is on the next line while I want it to be on the same line. Here is my code

https://codepen.io/ramizafzalkhan/pen/bGNaJXm

```css
div {
width: 300px;
height: 65px;
line-height: 1.4em;
display: flex;
-webkit-line-clamp: 3;
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
overflow: hidden; 
}
.fa{
display: -webkit-box;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css">
<div>
  
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat Lorem ipsum dolor sit
  amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat .

</div>
<i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
```

Comment: You need to show some code here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3):

```css
p {
  width: 300px;
  height: 65px;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.fa {
  display: -webkit-box;
  float: right;
  margin-top: -2em;
}

div {
  width: 325px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css">
<div>
  <p>

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat .

  </p>
  <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: solution worked.. with some changes, thanks for the help.....

Comment: your welcome
if solution helped mark it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

you have not used proper CSS, look into below code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css">
    <title>StackOver flow</title>
    <style>
        .main {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .main p {
            width: 300px;
            height: auto;
            line-height: 1.0em;
            font-size: 1.0em;
            display: inline-block;
            white-space: nowrap;
            overflow: hidden;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
        }

        .main span {
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 12px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="main">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat Lorem ipsum
            dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat .</p><span><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></span>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

[DEMO](https://codepen.io/Rameez_Bukhari/pen/NWPXQGa)

Answer (score 0):

you have placed the font-awesome's arrow icon outside of your div, that is why it appearing on the next line. The `<div>` tag is a block element, and everything outside of it will not be in line with the `<div>`. If you shift your `<i>` tag inside the `<div>...</div>`, then you will get the following.

[image]

There is still no arrow icon here, and that is because of your CSS file. You have restricted the `<div>` to be of 300px in `width` and 65px in `height`. If you change them both to 100%, you will get the following result.

[image]

You can play around with CSS to more fine-tune it. Have a look at my [codepen](https://codepen.io/AdityaPrakash/pen/mdypYWK) for it.